# How to create multiple objects in JSON from input in textarea?

Tags: javascript, json, dart

I have a problem. My users can write things down in the textarea and I would like to make sure that the first line in the WYISWYG editor is an object in JSON, the second line is an object in the WYISYG and so on.

**What is the actual problem?**

I need to separately style the three lines, so I need to get the elements one by one as an output. The problem is that now I have one object with a long string that I have to divide in three lines, which I can't do.

To illustrate what I mean:

Textarea --> someone writes:

1. Hello
2. I am an example
3. Hello 2

To get:

```
{"line 1":"<p>Hello<\/p>\"}
{"line 2":"<p>I am an example<\/p>\"}
{"line 3":"<p>Hello 2<\/p>\"}
```

Instead I get:

```
{"line 1":"<p>Hello<\/p>\n<p>I am an example<\/p>\n<p>Hello 2<\/p>\n"}
```

Could anyone help here?

Edit: I am parsing it like this:

```
openingtimes = parse(json["line1"] ?? "").documentElement!.text;
```

Comment: You can use [`.split("\n")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the `textarea`'s content into separate items in an array.

Comment: Where? After parsing the data in JSON or already in the textarea with PHP?

Comment: That depends on your script. Can you include a minimal working example of what you have?

Comment: I don't know how I can do that, I am afraid. Relatively new to JSON etc. The problem is that I have just 1 string that contains all three lines, so I can't separate them by targeting them... that's the whole issue.

Comment: Currently, this is how I parse it:  openingtimes = parse(json["line1"] ?? "").documentElement!.text;

Comment: Can you explain the flow of things? From your question I'm thinking: your have a `textarea`, then you get it's contents, then put that into a JSON object, right?

Comment: Correct! I have a textarea and this flows to JSON. The problem is that I am using the textarea in a manner that I want to output its contents per line.... but in JSON, I have just one object with the whole string that contains all lines. 

So when I parse JSON, I get the full string as one whole, while I want it in chunks (per line, based on the textarea break). I am even okay if I could just target a HTML element, even if that means I have to wrap it in e.g. <li> in my textarea.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the contents of the `textarea`, you can use `.split("\n")` to get the array of separate lines. (Note the use of `"` instead of `'`.)

If you then need to convert that array into an object, just create an empty object, loop through the lines array and add them to it.

Have a look at the different `console.log()`s output at every stage:

```js
function getTextareaContentsAsArray() {
    // Get the element
    let textarea = document.getElementById('the_editor');
    
    // Get the contents
    let contents = textarea.value;
    
    // Split by line ending
    let lines_array = contents.split("\n");
    console.log(lines_array);

    // Convert array to array of JSON
    let lines_object = {};
    lines_array
        // Remove empty lines
        .filter((v) => v.length)
        // Loop through all lines and add them to the_json object
        .map((line, index) => {
            lines_object[`line${index+1}`] = line;
        });
    console.log(lines_object);
    
    let json_as_string = JSON.stringify(lines_object);
    console.log(json_as_string);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="the_editor" cols="50" rows="5"><p>Hello</p>
<p>I am an example</p>
<p>Hello 2</p>
</textarea>

<button id="the_button" onclick="getTextareaContentsAsArray()">Get contents as array of lines</button>
```

Comment: I am getting an error in my PHP website when I try to add that functionality. Is that normal? The textarea is on a PHP website and I am trying to fetch it via JSON in Dart. Just FYI.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dart, but the `getTextareaContentsAsArray` function is JavaScript, so it would go on the front-end. I'm not sure how it's done in Dart, but in PHP there is also a function that can split a single string into an array based on a string: `$the_array = explode("\n", $the_string_to_split)` ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)).

Comment: In Dart you can also use [`.split()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dart-splitting-of-string/) in the same way as JavaScript.

Comment: I am trying to get it: where should I post this snippet? In the app that tries to fetch it as JSON or on my website that has the PHP textarea?

Comment: The code in my answer goes on the front-end (so in the javascript file). I assumed your situation was on the webpage front-end. If that's not the case, then please add a minimal example of your code/situation in your question so we can have a look. [See here for info on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)